# Select Class selector child div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how select the element under thumbSlider using Jquery

```
<div class="thumbSlider"> 

                <div class="graythumb showthumb">
                <div class="bluethumb">
</div>
```

I am familiar how to select a class doing

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.graythumb').hasClass('showthumb')) {
        alert('has class2');
    }
});
```

but I need to make sure that I would only be selecting element under thumbSlider class

in css it would be like

```
.thumbSlider .graythumb { display:none;}
.thumbSlider .graythumb .showthumb { display:block;}
```

Comment: jQuery (or sizzle) uses css selectors, so... -> [Selecting Elements | jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just like in CSS:

```
$(".thumbSlider .graythumb")      // Child
$(".thumbSlider > .graythumb")    // Immediate child
```

or using `.find()`

```
$(".thumbSlider").find(".graythumb")
```

When using a library make sure to take some time to go through their API:
https://api.jquery.com/
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

---

in your case would look like:

```
if ( $(".thumbSlider .graythumb").hasClass('showthumb')) {
// or
if ( $(".thumbSlider").find(".graythumb").hasClass('showthumb')) {
```

or if you want to make sure it applies only to the immediate children:

```
if ( $(".thumbSlider > .graythumb").hasClass('showthumb')) {
// or
if ( $(".thumbSlider").children(".graythumb").hasClass('showthumb')) {
// or
if ( $(".thumbSlider").find("> .graythumb").hasClass('showthumb')) {
```

Comment: what if I have a class like  <div class="one two"> <div class="three four"> would it be like .one.two .three.four ?

Comment: @JeVic exactly.